# PlayN / Tripleplay how to create two button in different screen location

Tags: playn

It is easy to create a button or button-group,

```
    Root root = iface.createRoot(AxisLayout.vertical(), ROOT, modeLayer).
            setStyles(make(VALIGN.top, HALIGN.right)).
            setBounds(0, 0, width, height).
            add(backButton);
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to create two button in different group, 
i.e.  one button on TOP-LEFT and on button on TOP-RIGHT...

I tried created two root, one button will be disabled/un-clickable.
if I crate one root, they will grouped together :(

============
Thanks samskivert for the detail answer, but I'm not able produce the correct result.
For the 1st suggestion in 'orginal' answer, full code as below:

```
    Font SMALL = PlayN.graphics().createFont("Helvetica", Font.Style.PLAIN, 24);
    final Stylesheet ROOT = SimpleStyles.newSheetBuilder().
            add(Element.class, make(FONT.is(SMALL))).
            add(Button.class, make(BACKGROUND.is(Background.solid(100)))).create();

    Group group = new Group(AxisLayout.vertical()).add(
            new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.left).add(
                    new Button("Upper left")),
            AxisLayout.stretch(new Shim(1, 1)),
            new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.right).add(
                    new Button("Lower right")));

    iface.createRoot(AxisLayout.vertical(), ROOT, modeLayer)
            .setBounds(0, 0, 960, 640)
            .add(group);
```

it produce this screen (ie, it's all centered, instead of upper-left/lower-down...)
[image]

For the 2nd one, full code as below:
    Font SMALL = PlayN.graphics().createFont("Helvetica", Font.Style.PLAIN, 24);

```
    final Stylesheet ROOT = SimpleStyles.newSheetBuilder().
            add(Element.class, make(FONT.is(SMALL))).
            add(Button.class, make(BACKGROUND.is(Background.solid(100)))).create();

    Group group = new Group(new BorderLayout()).add(
      new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.left).
        setConstraint(BorderLayout.NORTH).add(
              new Button("Upper left")),
      new Group(AxisLayout.vertical(), Style.HALIGN.right).
        setConstraint(BorderLayout.SOUTH).add(
              new Button("Lower right")));

    iface.createRoot(AxisLayout.vertical(), ROOT, modeLayer)
            .setBounds(0, 0, 960, 640)
            .add(group);
```

it produce this screenshot (ie, it's centered *and* overlap...)
[image]

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Oops, now I see that you want top-left and top-right, not top-left and bottom-right. The configuration you want is even simpler. Just stick a stretched shim in between the buttons:

```
iface.createRoot(AxisLayout.vertical().offStretch(), ROOT, modeLayer).
  setBounds(0, 0, width, height).
  add(new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal()).add(
    new Button("Upper-left"),
    AxisLayout.stretch(new Shim(1, 1)),
    new Button("Upper-right")));
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

AxisLayout lays out all of its elements in a (horizontal or vertical) line. They all have to be next to each other, with a configurable gap in between. If you want to accomplish your desired layout with AxisLayout you need to use nested groups like so:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|+-------------------------------------+|
|| [Button]    left-aligned AxisLayout ||
|+-------------------------------------+|
|                                       |
|        [stretched shim widget]        |  <-- vertical AxisLayout
|                                       |
|+-------------------------------------+|
|| right-aligned AxisLayout   [Button] ||
|+-------------------------------------+|
+---------------------------------------+
```

In code, that looks like:

```
Group group = new Group(AxisLayout.vertical()).add(
  new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.left).add(
    new Button("Upper left")),
  AxisLayout.stretch(new Shim(1, 1)),
  new Group(AxisLayout.horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.right).add(
    new Button("Lower right")));
```

You can also use the BorderLayout to avoid the shim in the middle:

```
Group group = new Group(new BorderLayout()).add(
  new Group(AxisLayout().horizontal(), Style.HALIGN.left).
    setConstraint(BorderLayout.NORTH).add(
      new Button("Upper left")),
  new Group(AxisLayout.vertical(), Style.HALIGN.right).
    setConstraint(BorderLayout.SOUTH).add(
      new Button("Lower right")));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for the answer, but I couldn't get it working exactly as I wanted. I couldn't post screen-shot on comment so I expanded my question, btw, I'm using Tripleplay-1.3,  Thanks.